# Angular material mat-table not sorting when the column value is created with 2 values

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am trying to sort a mat-table alphabetically by a full name column. Column is defined as shown below

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="fullName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firstName}} {{element.lastName}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Problem is when the value in the `td` is only the first or the last name, it works just fine, but when merged into one to make the full name in the same column, sorting doesn't happen. Anyone has an idea of how to make this possible? I've tried to put it like `{{element.firstName + " " + element.lastName}}` too but didn't work either. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You can create custom sorting, check example https://stackblitz.com/edit/mattable-with-sorting-custom?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts

Comment: Thank you! your example helped me a lot